# Linux Headers Vulnerabilities on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, security, ubuntu-18.04

We have internal and external SLA's that we adhere to with regards to fixing vulnerabilities of a critical nature.

Currently, we are running 18.04 LTS. The MOTD says:

102 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

But our CVSS/Vulnerability Monitor is reporting that:

Upgrade linux-headers-5.4.0-1029-aws
Upgrade linux-aws-5.4-headers-5.4.0-1029
Upgrade linux-image-5.4.0-1029-aws
Upgrade linux-modules-5.4.0-1029-aws

Are all subject to:

CVE-2021-1052, CVE-2020-28374, CVE-2020-14351, CVE-2020-16120, CVE-2020-4788

Which are all rated as "HIGH"

[Vulnerabilities listed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAl7G.png)

Should we not expect package upgrades for this? Is the CVSS database treating this different than Ubuntu?

Thanks for the help to keep everything locked up tight.

Comment: These security updates were released already. Check to see if you have them installed already but forgot to reboot. And check you didn't disable the security or updates repos.

Comment: Indeed, you should be at 1037 at this point. What version are you actually running? Is it a matter of not getting old versions cleaned up or are you far behind on the kernel versions?

Comment: Thanks to you both. I just had to do a reboot and all was right with the world. I wish the MOTD was a little more verbose that the package may be installed but you need to reboot. It was a little vague. Thanks.